# Android - CollapsingToolbarLayout setHomeButtonEnabled

Tags: java, android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm having trouble implementing HomeUpEnabled when using `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, I can see the icon but noting happens when I press it.

Here is the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

avivity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#80000000" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Activity.java

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I have declared the activity in my manifest. Any help would be appreciated.

----------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------

THIS IS WHAT FIXED IT:

I don't know if it is correct, but it works.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();


    finish();
}
```

And in my xml I changed the background of the toolbar to:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

to get the ripple effect on the icon.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Overrited Following method and specify your action in  method block with menu id as home :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);  // OPEN DRAWER
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

Comment: at the moment it is `@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.home){
            super. onBackPressed();
            finish(); } return true;
    }`

Comment: If you are seeing home icon then you can access, click event that icon using onOptionsItemSelected() selected method which I suggest in  my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the parent activity name in your manifest.xml

Your code is correct but only displays the back arrow on your toolbar, you have to tell your activity which is the activity to come back to.

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity" android:parentActivityName="YourParentActivity" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, Create 3 different xml file for activity_main, app_bar and content_main

app_bar

```
android:id="@+id/app_bar"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"

android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"

    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

        android:id="@+id/toolbar"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

        android:id="@+id/tabs"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

        android:layout_gravity="bottom"

        app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"


        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"

        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

        app:tabGravity="fill"

        app:tabMode="fixed"/>



</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

**content_main**

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="MainActivity"

tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">



    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

        android:id="@+id/tabs_viewpager"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**activity_main**

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/toolbar"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

    android:layout_gravity="top"

    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

    app:title="" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

    <include

        layout="@layout/app_bar"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_gravity="start"

        android:id="@+id/mystuff"

        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I have a recyclerView underneath my CollapsingToolbar.